# Request clarification of Gradle task rule syntax from documentation

Tags: groovy, gradle, task, rules

Pursuant to this spot in the Gradle documentation:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F07

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: ping<ID>") { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.startsWith("ping")) {
        task(taskName) << {
            println "Pinging: " + (taskName - 'ping')
        }
    }
}
```

It says, ***"Sometimes you want to have a task whose behavior depends on a large or infinite number value range of parameters. A very nice and expressive way to provide such tasks are task rules."***.

It's not at all clear to me from this block of code how those parameters are defined nor how they get into the task scope so that they can be used.

It's also not clear if they have to be all the same type. I really need an example that shows these.

I'm not a Groovy guy in the first place. Gradle is my reason for learning Groovy.

Comment: OK part of the problem is that I didn't know that you have to do task configuration in a configuration block. I know that now but it's only part of the puzzle.

Comment: I've created a configuration but now I can't access the values I'm storing in it. Also I can't get a task with dependencies to aggregate tasks.